# How to apply a global controller filter in spree and gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm trying to apply an `around_filter` on all the controllers of a Spree 2.3+ application.

I got this mostly working but the filter is not applied to all the extra gem controllers, such as the ones of the `spree_devise_auth` gem, which apparently inherits from a number of classes.

In fact when I visit any controller rendered by the gem the filters are just skipped.

```
# app/controllers/spree/base_controller_decorator.rb

Spree::BaseController.class_eval do
  prepend_around_filter :my_method
```

Is there a solution to this beside enumerating every single controller in the gems and performing a `class_eval`?

Comment: What do you want to solve/implement with the `around_filter`?

Comment: I'm writing multi-tenancy (multiple stores under the same codebase) separated by Postgres schemas, the filter serves the purpose to set said schema before each call.

Comment: Ok. Have you explore [spree_multi_tenant][1] or [apartment][2]?


  [1]: https://github.com/stefansenk/spree_multi_tenant
  [2]: https://github.com/influitive/apartment

Comment: yes I did, I update spree_multi_tenant for Spree 2.3 but I found out it's kinda useless for using PG schemas, the multitenant gem is fine though. Anyway spree_multi_tenant works (kinda) by enumerating all the classes that needs injection, and I was trying to go without this method. But apartment looks good, going to try it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your need a very good option is [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment). [Ryan Bigg](http://ryanbigg.com/), the former Spree  Community Manager, wrote the book "[Multitenancy with Rails And subscriptions too!](https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails)" from which I was a beta reviewer, it is very good. For Spree 2.4.0 at master is a work on to include multi-store/multi-domain for Spree as you can see at https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/4888/files

Comment: I'm playing with pg schemas, it's a HUGE mess but I'm getting there, thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm glad to ear about that